# python linked structure - inserting child to node A's parent is also inserting to node A

Tags: python, tree, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

I'm trying to implement a linked structure for a tree using python
this is an extract of my code

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,value,father=None,children=[]):
        self.value=value
        self.father=father
        self.children=children
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```

```
class Tree(object):

    def __init__(self,root=None):
        self.root=root
    def insertNode(self,new_node,father_value):
        father_node=self.find_node(father_value)
        if not father_node:
            return False
        new_node.father=father_node
        print("Node's information BEFORE adding child to father's list of children")
        print(f"Father node (find) {father_node}")
        print(f"Father node's children {[x.value for x in father_node.children]}")
        print(f"New node's father {new_node.father}")
        print(f"New node's children {[x.value for x in new_node.children]}")
        father_node.children.append(new_node)
        print("Node's information AFTER adding child to father's list of children")
        print(f"Father node (find) {father_node}")
        print(f"Father node's children {[x.value for x in father_node.children]}")
        print(f"New node's father {new_node.father}")
        print(f"New node's children {[x.value for x in new_node.children]}")

    def find_node(self,value):
        stack=[self.root]
        while True:
            if len(stack)==0:
                return False
            node=stack.pop()
            if node.value==value:
                return node
            children=node.children
            stack.extend(children)
```

```
n1=Node("A")
tree=Tree(n1)
tree.insertNode(Node("B"),"A")

n1=Node("A")
tree=Tree(n1)
tree.insertNode(Node("B"),"A")
```

the OUTPUT is

```
Node's information BEFORE adding child to father's list of children

Father node (find) A
Father node's children []
New node's father A
New node's children []
Node's information AFTER adding child to father's list of children
Father node (find) A
Father node's children ['B']
New node's father A
New node's children ['B']
```

As you can see, when I append the new inserted node into the father's children list it also inserts into the new node's list of children. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because of how Python deals with default values of optional parameters of a function.

In `class Node(object)`, you have this line:

```
def __init__(self,value,father=None,children=[]):
```

Python evaluates the default value `[]` **only once** (creating an empty `list` object), and then reuses that evaluated value (reference to that `list` object) **for all subsequent invocations** of that function.

In your case the function is the `__init__()` function, which gets invoked each time you instantiate the `Node` class. If you instantiate `Node` multiple times without explicitly passing in a third argument, in all those invocations of `__init__()`, the parameter `children` gets assigned the **same** `list` object as the default value. You are using this value to set the `children` attribute of all these instances. In other words, for all those `Node` instances, the `children` attribute would be pointing to the same `list` object. That is why inserting a child to the "father" `Node` is also adding the same child to the current `Node`.

The correct way to re-write `__init__()` would be:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,value,father=None,children=None):
        self.value=value
        self.father=father
        self.children=children if children is not None else []
```

## Moral

The general moral here is that, if your parameter's default value is a **mutable** object, it can throw surprises like this -- where, unknown to you, multiple references are stored to a single object, and mutations (changes) to the object through one reference, will also get reflected (seen) through the other references.

This is all documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#index-22)